# Widget is opening faster than the keyboard closes

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have the following code which either opens the keyboard and closes another custom widget or opens the custom widget and closes the keyboard.
The `showCustomTab` variable controls when to open that custom widget.

The problem I have is that when the keyboard is opened (so the showCustomTab is set to false) and I click the icon, the custom tab opens faster than the keyboard closes therefore, for a split second, I have a screen overflow because both the keyboard and the custom are showed (not visible with human eye but still throws overflow error).

So the problem I have is when switching between keyboard and custom widget. When the custom widget is shown and I open the keyboard this doesn't happen so only the other way around.

I've added that extra unfocus

```
if (chatFocusNode.hasFocus) {
  chatFocusNode.unfocus();
}
```

section before `showCustomTab = !showCustomTab;` but still I couldn't make it work.

Below is the full code:

```
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(
                  () {
                    menuProvider.closeAll();
                    if (chatFocusNode.hasFocus) {
                      chatFocusNode.unfocus();
                    }
                    cursorPosition = chatTextEditingController.selection;
                    showCustomTab = !showCustomTab;
                    if (showCustomTab) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(unUsed);
                    } else {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(chatFocusNode);
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                showCustomTab ? Icons.keyboard : Icons.insert_emoticon,
                color: showCustomTab
                    ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                    : Colors.black87,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
```

I've tried to manually close the keyboard (from the android emulator) then open the custom tab and it works so I know this is where I have the bug. Tried a bunch of things but couldn't make it work.